# List folders/files by group from terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, ls

From terminal (`ls -la`) I need to list files and folders **that are not** in a specific group.

Ex.: Given the group A B, ..., and Z, I need to list all folders and files that are not in group Z. This would list from A to Y.

`user1   A   123`

`user2   B   456`

As now I have `find . -group Z -maxdepth 1`

How do I "not" a find?

This list would then be pipe and cat in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Just negate the `-group` test with `!`:

```
find . ! -group Z -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: To run this from an interactive shell that has history expansion turned on (the default), use `\!` instead of `!`.